# Searching function on displayed SQL table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a question in relation to a MySQL table. Currently I am using the code below, in order to display a complete SQL table to a user

```
<?php;
    try {
  $con= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=members1', "mcxjb", "password");
  $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users";

  //first pass just gets the column names
  print "<table> \n";
  $result = $con->query($query);
  //return only the first row (we only need field names)
  $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  print " <tr> \n";
  foreach ($row as $field => $value){
   print " <th>$field</th> \n";
  } // end foreach
  print " </tr> \n";
  //second query gets the data
  $data = $con->query($query);
  $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach($data as $row){
   print " <tr> \n";
   foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
   print " <td>$value</td> \n";
   } // end field loop
   print " </tr> \n";
  } // end record loop
  print "</table> \n";
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
  } // end try

}

?>
```

And it displays the required information perfectly! However, I was wondering is there a way to implement a simple HTML form that allows the user to enter characters and it searches through the table, or perhaps narrows it down to the different items with them terms? I know it can be done with JavaScript but was wondering if it could be done with PHP.

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: with php you would rebuild the query with your search terms and submit that

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/), it's a js library, I recommend it :)

And using PHP, just add something like:  `$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE yourfield='".$_GET['search']."'";`

Comment: Cheers dude! Will try them out!